# Devise a backtracking algorithm to allocate $p$ projects to $s$ students

Tags: algorithms, backtracking

There are $p$ projects and $s$ students where $p \le s$. Multiple students can work on the same project but the same student cannot work on multiple projects. All projects must be allocated and all students must have a project. I need to compute and display all possible ways of allocating projects to students under these constraints. Here's an example:

Input:

3 students, 2 projects

Output:

```
   P1      P2
   {1}     {2, 3}
   {2}     {1, 3}
   {3}     {1, 2}
   {1, 2}  {3}
   {1, 3}  {2}
   {2, 3}  {1}
```

In my attempts, I've thought about this as being related to the problem of partitioning the set of students into non empty subsets and then ignoring those partitions which have unacceptable length. i.e. for my example generate:

```
{{1}, {2}, {3}}
{{1}, {2, 3}}
{{2}, {1, 3}}
{{3}, {1, 2}}
{{1, 2, 3}}
```

and ignore the first and last as well as double count the three in the middle as they can be arranged in a two ways (order matters for this problem). I'm not sure however how I would go about generating and filtering these subsets and even whether this is a decent solution for any p or s values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get what you're exatly asking for? Backtracking **is** the solution. Are you looking for an actual implementation or an explanation of backtracking? Or a  better  performing approach in terms of runtime.

Here my pseudo code how I would generate all matching solutions.

```
state = [];  //array representing the current state, assigns students to projects

S = [..];    //array containing the students
P = [..];    //array with students
func assign(level) {
  if(level == S.length) {
    if is_valid_state() //ensure each project has at least one student
      output(state);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < P.length; i++) {
    state[level] = i;
    assign(level+1);
  }
}

level(0)
```

Can of course  be optimized by moving the final condition atop, but this would be my first thought of how to solving this the least efficient way (in terms of performance).

Comment: I guess I'm looking for an implementation. I've updated my question a bit with a simple example and one of my attempts at reasoning about the problem.

Comment: Your pseudo code is a bit too abstract and I'm not sure how it goes about turning the given input into the proper solution. Maybe if you can add a bit more detail to it I'll be able to better grasp it and then get back to you with some proper questions, if any.

Comment: @Alex Pseudocode is, by its very nature, somewhat abstract. An actual implementation in an actual programming language would be off-topic here, as understanding it would depend almost as much on understanding the details of the particular language chosen as it would on understanding the underlying problem. Is there something more specific you don't understand about the algorithm? "I'm not sure how it goes about turning the given input into the proper solution" is essentially the same as "I'm not sure how any of it works."

Comment: Indeed, abstract is fine, but this one is a "bit too abstract" for my capabilities, hence the request for more details, if possible. My asking for an implementation was a bit of a mistake. I'm not looking for c code or something. Just a more detailed exposition of the solution.

Comment: And yes, I don't really understand how any of it works. That's why I was looking for more details. I'm not sure what level is, what P holds, nor how state as an array is supposed to work.

Comment: you wont possibly learn anything by just c&p, but here working js code. That should be easyily altered to perform in c as well. var to int etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/g1z5n61f/

the output is different than yours, the state says which project each student should attend:

"[0,0,1]"  //first two students attend project 0, kast student project 1
"[0,1,0]"
"[0,1,1]"
"[1,0,0]"
"[1,0,1]"
"[1,1,0]"

Comment: Well, thank you very much, that is actually far more than what I needed to get this, but is greatly appreciated. I actually pretty much understood your pseudo code by now but was a bit confused in the beginning but some typos like P = [] // array with students (actually projects) and level(0) which should be assign(0).

Comment: Next time I will spend more time taking in answers before relegating to daft comments like "I don't get it, add more details". Despite some typos your pseudo code is actually fairly easy to comprehend. So sorry for acting a bit dumb. Lesson learned.